# How to return multi table in postgres without refcursor?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, return

I have one SQL query like where I am returning two tables. How to return two tables in postgres?

```
 create proc sp_fetchResult
    as
    begin
    select * from TBl_Users;
    select * from TBl_Log;
    end;
```

How to do it in postgres function? The structure of those two tables is not same. I need two individual result sets in the form of table like table [0] and table[1].  I need to return only these two select statements from function.

Comment: Give details on the structure of both tables, and the structure of the desired output. And remove the java tag as this is pure postgres.

Comment: structure of those two tables is not same. I need two individual result set in the form of table like table  [0] and table[1]. pls tell me how to do ---create proc sp_fetchResult as begin select * from TBl_Users; select * from TBl_Log; end; in postgres

Comment: select FirstName, LastName from TBl_Users; select TaskId,CreatedBy from TBl_Log; I need to return only this two select statements from function

Comment: ref cursors are currently your only option

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately current PostgreSQL 10 does not allow it. From stored function you can return only type TABLE with defined structure or SETOF with user defined type.

But you cannot return simply result set or more result sets without declared structure (as you can in MySQL or MS SQL). Currently only possibility is - as you mentioned - refcursor. See here: http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/return_result_set_from_stored_procedure

But there is PostgreSQL 11 coming which implements stored procedures - see here: https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-11-server-side-procedures-part-1/

At the end of the article you can see that they want to implement "Returning multiple result sets".